# htaccess - how to include the (incorrect) file name with the 404 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, custom-error-pages

I have an htaccess file with a 404 redirect, like:

```
ErrorDocument   404 /?404
```

in which a 404 message is presented. In order to take care of things depending on what file name / URI caused the 404, I would need to know the (incorrect) file name in my 404 PHP file. How is that done...?

Novice-like, I tried

```
ErrorDocument   404 /?404&p=%{REQUEST_URI}
```

which did not work. Is there a way to include the file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requested file (that did not exist) was of course accessible in the 404 file by:

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
```

Problem solved.